# Can we use Kafka just for queuing purpose without storing on to the disk? If so how can we achieve it?

Tags: apache-kafka

Hi I am using kafka in my application for queuing. I am pumping 75k records/sec to my application which will be queued by kafka. My application is deployed on openstack vms. Due to some infrastructure issues when kafka is storing those records onto the disk i am facing CRC issues which is related to record corruption . Below is the exception :

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Error deserializing key/value for partition TcpMessage-3 at offset 1331363158
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:628) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.handleFetchResponse(Fetcher.java:566) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$000(Fetcher.java:69) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$1.onSuccess(Fetcher.java:139) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$1.onSuccess(Fetcher.java:136) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:380) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:274) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:320) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:213) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:193) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:908) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:853) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.affirmed.mediation.edr.kafka.tcpMessage.TcpMessageConsumer.doWork(TcpMessageConsumer.java:196) [EdrServer.jar:?]
        at com.affirmed.mediation.edr.kafka.tcpMessage.TcpMessageConsumer.run(TcpMessageConsumer.java:255) [EdrServer.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.record.InvalidRecordException: **Record is corrupt (stored crc = 2053731240, computed crc = 2767221639)**
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.Record.ensureValid(Record.java:226) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:617) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
        ... 15 more
```

So is there any way to use kafka just for queuing without storing the records onto disk? If yes, how can we achieve it?

Comment: Just a comment that version 0.9 of Kafka is almost 2 years old and you may want to consider upgrading to get some of the new features Ike in 0.11 you can programmatically delete all messages in the queue older than the offset you have processed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there any way to use kafka just for queuing without storing the records onto disk? If yes, how can we achieve it?

In general, no, this is not possible.

What you could perhaps do as a (crude!) workaround is to use a [RAM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) and configure your Kafka brokers to store their data on this RAM drive.  Of course, using a RAM drive has several downsides such as having a big risk of data loss because data is not persistent to durable storage.  It also assumes that the memory of your OpenStack VMs does not suffer from the same corruption issues like their disks.

Perhaps a better approach would be to fix your OpenStack environment...?